# PublishSubject with Kotlin coroutines (Flow)

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines

I used a PublishSubject and I was sending messages to it and also I was listening for results. It worked flawlessly, but now I'm not sure how to do the same thing with Kotlin's coroutines (flows or channels).

```
private val subject = PublishProcessor.create<Boolean>>()

...

fun someMethod(b: Boolean) {
    subject.onNext(b)
}

fun observe() {
    subject.debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
           .subscribe { /* value received */ }
}
```

Since I need the debounce operator I really wanted to do the same thing with flows so I created a channel and then I tried to create a flow from that channel and listen to changes, but I'm not getting any results.

```
private val channel = Channel<Boolean>()

...

fun someMethod(b: Boolean) {
    channel.send(b)
}

fun observe() {
    flow {
         channel.consumeEach { value ->
            emit(value)
         }
    }.debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .onEach {
        // value received
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[`Flow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/index.html) is a cold asynchronous stream, just like an `Observable`.

> All transformations on the flow, such as `map` and `filter` do not trigger flow collection or execution, only terminal operators (e.g. `single`) do trigger it.

The `onEach` method is just a transformation. Therefore you should replace it with the terminal flow operator `collect`. Also you could use a `BroadcastChannel` to have cleaner code:

```
private val channel = BroadcastChannel<Boolean>(1)

suspend fun someMethod(b: Boolean) {
    channel.send(b)
}

suspend fun observe() {
  channel
    .asFlow()
    .debounce(500)
    .collect {
        // value received
    }
}
```

<sub>**Update:** At the time the question was asked there was an overload of `debounce` with two parameters (like in the question). There is not anymore. But now there is one which takes one argument in milliseconds (Long).</sub>

Comment: Could you share solving the issue?

Comment: @CaferMertCeyhan mayyyo was missing to subscribe to the `Flow`. This is done with `collect` instead of `onEach`.

Comment: @tynn I updated your answer regarding an API change. Pls revise in case you don't like it. :)

Comment: Worth saying that `BroadcastChannel` is still experimental.

Comment: `BroadcastChannel` has been deprecated in 1.5 in favor of `SharedFlow` and `StateFlow`.

Answer (score 34):

It should be [`SharedFlow/MutableSharedFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/index.html) for `PublishProcessor/PublishRelay`

```kotlin
private val _myFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Boolean>(
                          replay = 0,
                          extraBufferCapacity = 1, // you can increase      
                          BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
)
val myFlow = _myFlow.asSharedFlow()


// ...
fun someMethod(b: Boolean) {
    _myFlow.tryEmit(b)
}

fun observe() {
    myFlow.debounce(500)
          .onEach {  }
          // flowOn(), catch{}
          .launchIn(coroutineScope)

}
```

And [`StateFlow/MutableStateFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-state-flow/index.html) for `BehaviorProcessor/BehaviorRelay`.

```kotlin
private val _myFlow = MutableStateFlow<Boolean>(false)
val myFlow = _myFlow.asStateFlow()

// ...
fun someMethod(b: Boolean) {
    _myFlow.value = b // same as _myFlow.emit(v), myFlow.tryEmit(b)
}

fun observe() {
    myFlow.debounce(500)
          .onEach {  }
          // flowOn(), catch{}
          .launchIn(coroutineScope)

}
```

`StateFlow` must have initial value, if you don't want that, this is workaround:

```kotlin
private val _myFlow = MutableStateFlow<Boolean?>(null)
val myFlow = _myFlow.asStateFlow()
                    .filterNotNull()
```

`MutableStateFlow` uses `.equals` comparison when setting new value, so it does not emit same value again and again (versus `distinctUntilChanged` which uses referential comparison).

So `MutableStateFlow` ≈ `BehaviorProcessor.distinctUntilChanged()`. If you want exact `BehaviorProcessor` behavior then you can use this:

```kotlin
private val _myFlow = MutableSharedFlow<Boolean>(
                              replay = 1, 
                              extraBufferCapacity = 0,
                              BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST
)
```

Comment: this answer should be accepted. Shared flows were made as a replacement for BroadcastChannels (which jetbrains folks [consider a design deadend](https://elizarov.medium.com/shared-flows-broadcast-channels-899b675e805c) now)

Answer (score 6):

ArrayBroadcastChannel in Kotlin coroutines is the one most similar to PublishSubject.

1. Like PublishSubject, an ArrayBroadcastChannel can have multiple
   subscribers and all the active subscribers are immediately notified.
2. Like PublishSubject, events pushed to this channel are lost, if there are no active subscribers at the moment.

Unlike PublishSubject, backpressure is inbuilt into the coroutine channels, and that is where the buffer capacity comes in. This number really depends on which use case the channel is being used for. For most of the normal use cases, I just go with 10, which should be more than enough. If you push events faster to this channel than receivers consuming it, you can give more capacity.

Comment: How can I use it? Could you provide some initialization code, please? Android Studio does not resolve ArrayBroadcastChannel.

Comment: Just for everyone who found this comment: ArrayBroadcastChannel is an internal class, but according to javadoc: "This channel is created by `BroadcastChannel(capacity)` factory function invocation." - so all you need to do is create a usual BroadcastChannel and pass capacity to its constructor, like - BroadcastChannel(1).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Indeed, sending to `BroadcastChannel` with no subscribers does not trigger buffering/backpressure, unlike with regular `Channel`. Could not find this in the docs.

Comment: Note: This API is obsolete. It will be deprecated and replaced by SharedFlow when it becomes stable.

https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-broadcast-channel/

Answer (score 3):

Actually `BroadcastChannel` is obsolete already, Jetbrains changed their approach to use `SharedFlows` instead. Which is a lot more cleaner, easier to implement and solves a lot of pain points.

Essentially, you can achieve the same thing like this.

```kotlin
class BroadcastEventBus {
    private val _events = MutableSharedFlow<Event>()
    val events = _events.asSharedFlow() // read-only public view

    suspend fun postEvent(event: Event) {
        _events.emit(event) // suspends until subscribers receive it
    }
}
```

To read about it more, checkout Roman's Medium article.

["Shared flows, broadcast channels" by Roman Elizarov](https://elizarov.medium.com/shared-flows-broadcast-channels-899b675e805c)