# Is there a way to achieve this rx flow in Kotlin with coroutines/Flow/Channels?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying out Kotlin Coroutines and Flow for the first time and I am trying to reproduce a certain flow I use on Android with RxJava with an MVI-ish approach, but I am having difficulties getting it right and I am essentially stuck at this point.

The RxJava app looks essentially like this:

### MainActivityView.kt

```kotlin
object MainActivityView {

    sealed class Event {
        object OnViewInitialised : Event()
    }

    data class State(
        val renderEvent: RenderEvent = RenderEvent.None
    )

    sealed class RenderEvent {
        object None : RenderEvent()
        class DisplayText(val text: String) : RenderEvent()
    }
}
```

#### MainActivity.kt

MainActivity has an instance of a `PublishSubject` with a `Event` type. Ie `MainActivityView.Event.OnViewInitialised`, `MainActivityView.Event.OnError` etc. The initial Event is sent in `onCreate()` via the subjects's `.onNext(Event)` call.

```kotlin
@MainActivityScope
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var subscriptions: CompositeDisposable

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: MainActivityViewModel

    @Inject
    lateinit var onViewInitialisedSubject: PublishSubject<MainActivityView.Event.OnViewInitialised>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setupEvents()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        subscriptions.clear()
    }

    private fun setupEvents() {
        if (subscriptions.size() == 0) {
            Observable.mergeArray(
                onViewInitialisedSubject
                    .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                    .toObservable()
            ).observeOn(
                Schedulers.io()
            ).compose(
                viewModel()
            ).observeOn(
                AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()
            ).subscribe(
                ::render
            ).addTo(
                subscriptions
            )

            onViewInitialisedSubject
                .onNext(
                    MainActivityView
                        .Event
                        .OnViewInitialised
                )
        }
    }

    private fun render(state: MainActivityView.State) {
        when (state.renderEvent) {
            MainActivityView.RenderEvent.None -> Unit
            is MainActivityView.RenderEvent.DisplayText -> {
                mainActivityTextField.text = state.renderEvent.text
            }
        }
    }

}
```

#### MainActivityViewModel.kt

These `Event`'s are then picked up by a `MainActivityViewModel` class which is invoked by `.compose(viewModel())` which then transform the received `Event` into a sort of a new `State` via `ObservableTransformer<Event, State>`. The viewmodel returns a new state with a `renderEvent` in it, which can then be acted upon in the `MainActivity` again via `render(state: MainActivityView.State)`function.

```kotlin
@MainActivityScope
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private var state: MainActivityView.State
) {

    operator fun invoke(): ObservableTransformer<MainActivityView.Event, MainActivityView.State> = onEvent

    private val onEvent = ObservableTransformer<MainActivityView.Event,
        MainActivityView.State> { upstream: Observable<MainActivityView.Event> ->
        upstream.publish { shared: Observable<MainActivityView.Event> ->
            Observable.mergeArray(
                shared.ofType(MainActivityView.Event.OnViewInitialised::class.java)
            ).compose(
                eventToViewState
            )
        }
    }

    private val eventToViewState = ObservableTransformer<MainActivityView.Event, MainActivityView.State> { upstream ->
        upstream.flatMap { event ->
            when (event) {
                MainActivityView.Event.OnViewInitialised -> onViewInitialisedEvent()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun onViewInitialisedEvent(): Observable<MainActivityView.State> {
        val renderEvent = MainActivityView.RenderEvent.DisplayText(text = "hello world")
        state = state.copy(renderEvent = renderEvent)
        return state.asObservable()
    }

}
```

Could I achieve sort of the same flow with coroutines/Flow/Channels? Possibly a bit simplified even?

### EDIT:

I have since found a solution that works for me, I haven't found any issues thus far. However this solution uses `ConflatedBroadcastChannel<T>` which eventually will be deprecated, it will likely be possible to replace it with (at the time of writing) not yet released `SharedFlow` api (more on that [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2034).

The way it works is that the `Activity` and viewmodel shares
a `ConflatedBroadcastChannel<MainActivity.Event>` which is used to send or offer events from the `Activity` (or an adapter). The viewmodel reduce the event to a new State which is then emitted. The `Activity` is collecting on the `Flow<State>` returned by `viewModel.invoke()`, and ultimately renders the emitted `State`.

### MainActivityView.kt

```kotlin
object MainActivityView {

    sealed class Event {
        object OnViewInitialised : Event()
        data class OnButtonClicked(val idOfItemClicked: Int) : Event()
    }

    data class State(
        val renderEvent: RenderEvent = RenderEvent.Idle
    )

    sealed class RenderEvent {
        object Idle : RenderEvent()
        data class DisplayText(val text: String) : RenderEvent()
    }
}
```

### MainActivity.kt

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: MainActivityViewModel

    @Inject
    lateinit eventChannel: ConflatedBroadcastChannel<MainActivityView.Event>

    private var isInitialised: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        init()
    }
    
    private fun init() {
        if (!isInitialised) {
            
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                viewModel()
                    .flowOn(
                        Dispatchers.IO
                    ).collect(::render)
            }

            eventChannel
                .offer(
                    MainActivityView.Event.OnViewInitialised
                )
            isInitialised = true
        }
    }

    private suspend fun render(state: MainActivityView.State): Unit =
        when (state.renderEvent) {
            MainActivityView.RenderEvent.Idle -> Unit
            is MainActivityView.RenderEvent.DisplayText -> 
                renderDisplayText(text = state.renderEvent.text)
            
        }

    private val renderDisplayText(text: String) {
        // render text
    }

}
```

### MainActivityViewModel.kt

```
class MainActivityViewModel constructor(
    private var state: MainActivityView.State = MainActivityView.State(),
    private val eventChannel: ConflatedBroadcastChannel<MainActivityView.Event>,
 ) {

    suspend fun invoke(): Flow<MainActivityView.State> =
        eventChannel
            .asFlow()
            .flatMapLatest { event: MainActivityView.Event ->
                reduce(event)
            }

    private fun reduce(event: MainActivityView.Event): Flow<MainActivityView.State> =
        when (event) {
            MainActivityView.Event.OnViewInitialised -> onViewInitialisedEvent()
            MainActivityView.Event.OnButtonClicked -> onButtonClickedEvent(event.idOfItemClicked)
        }

    private fun onViewInitialisedEvent(): Flow<MainActivityView.State> = flow 
        val renderEvent = MainActivityView.RenderEvent.DisplayText(text = "hello world")
        state = state.copy(renderEvent = renderEvent)
        emit(state)
    }

    private fun onButtonClickedEvent(idOfItemClicked: Int): Flow<MainActivityView.State> = flow 
        // do something to handle click
        println("item clicked: $idOfItemClicked")
        emit(state)
    }

}
```

Similiar questions:

- [publishsubject-with-kotlin-coroutines-flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56111292/publishsubject-with-kotlin-coroutines-flow)

Comment: Yes you can achieve this with a `BroadcastChannel` and `asFlow()`.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I am having trouble understanding how the BroadcastChannel works.

Answer (score 1):

Your `MainActivity` can look something like this.

```
@MainActivityScope
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {

    @Inject
    lateinit var subscriptions: CompositeDisposable

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModel: MainActivityViewModel

    @Inject
    lateinit var onViewInitialisedChannel: BroadcastChannel<MainActivityView.Event.OnViewInitialised>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setupEvents()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        subscriptions.clear()
    }

    private fun setupEvents() {
        if (subscriptions.size() == 0) {
            onViewInitialisedChannel.asFlow()
                .buffer()
                .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                .onEach(::render)
                .launchIn(GlobalScope)

            onViewInitialisedChannel
                .offer(
                    MainActivityView
                        .Event
                        .OnViewInitialised
                )
        }
    }

    private fun render(state: MainActivityView.State) {
        when (state.renderEvent) {
            MainActivityView.RenderEvent.None -> Unit
            is MainActivityView.RenderEvent.DisplayText -> {
                mainActivityTextField.text = state.renderEvent.text
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Dominic, thank you. But maybe I wasnt clear enough or maybe im misunderrstanding, but I dont see how this fits into the problem I have. The problem is to dispatch an 'event' to the 'viewmodel' and let the viewmodel transform the event into a new state which is then returned and rendered by the render function in the fragment. I am not rendering the 'event' class immediatly as suggested by your example, what is rendered however is the state which is returned back by the vm. I dont see any call to the vm in your example, also what if there is more events? for example OnButtonClickEvent etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the Flow version of `compose` and `ObservableTransformer` and as far as I can tell there isn't one. What you can use instead is the `let` operator and do something *like* this:

MainActivity:

```
yourFlow
  .let(viewModel::invoke)
  .onEach(::render)
  .launchIn(lifecycleScope) // or viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope if you're in a fragment
```

ViewModel:

```
operator fun invoke(viewEventFlow: Flow<Event>): Flow<State> = viewEventFlow.flatMapLatest { event ->
  when (event) {
    Event.OnViewInitialised -> flowOf(onViewInitialisedEvent())
  }
}
```

As far as sharing a flow I would watch these issues:

- https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2034
- https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2047

Dominic's answer might work for replacing the publish subjects but I think the coroutines team is moving away from `BroadcastChannel` and intends to deprecate it in the near future.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back in a timely manner. I have updated my post with the solution I currently use. It does use the ConflatedBroadcastChannel<T> API which (like you pointed out) will be deprecated in the future. Hopefully it will be possible to replace it with SharedFlow.

Answer (score 0):

kotlinx-coroutines-core provides a `transform` function.

https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/transform.html

it isn't quite the same as what we are used to in RxJava but should be usable for achieving the same result.